# Using Ajax to post a form, no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Django version 1.11.1
I have a form on my `template`, wanna use ajax to post it which can only change the form, my form code like:

```
<form action="" class="poster" id="posterForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="img_input" class="file_btn">
    <input type="button" class="file_front_btn" value="选择图片" name="image">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="title_area" placeholder="标题（不超过20字）：">
    <span class="img_root">已选图片：<span id="img_root" class="hidden">无</span></span>
    <textarea name="content" id="content" name="content" class="content_area" placeholder="输入内容（不超过2000字）："></textarea>
    <div id="title_error"></div>
    <div id="content_error"></div>
    <input type="button" class="submit" id="submitBtn" value="发布">
    <div id="img_error"></div>
</form>
```

And my `jQuery`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submitBtn').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url:"{% url 'community:poster' %}",
            data:$('#posterForm').serialize(),
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    $('#posterForm')[0].reset();
                    alert("发布成功")
                }else if(data.status == 'fail'){
                    $('#img_error').html(data.msg)
                }
            },
        });
    });
})
```

And my `views` is:

```
class PosterView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        poster_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if poster_form.is_valid():
            poster = poster_form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponse("{'status':'success'}", content_type='application/json')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("{'status':'fail', 'msg':{0}}".format(poster_form.errors), content_type='application/json')
```

I use a `ModelForm` to commit the form, the forms is:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['image', 'title', 'content']
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns =[
url(r'^allpost/$', AllPosts.as_view(), name='allpost'),
url(r'^poster/$', PosterView.as_view(), name='poster'),
```

]

I can't see where the problem is, but when I click the submit button, nothing happened, no fail status.

Comment: have you checked the console?? and is jquery loaded before the ajax call??

Comment: the console says `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

Comment: yes that means the jquery is not loaded, you need to load jquery

Comment: I loaded jQuery and console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: It return a KeyError: u"'status'", but I passing this key in my views

Comment: there is no input named status in the form? then how are you going to get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150449/discussion-between-klawens-and-exprator).

Comment: provide your urls.py please

Comment: ok @Shaon shaonty

Comment: have you registered the app community in urls ?

Comment: of course I did